# Is there a configuration or hook so that after adding a product I can be redirected to the shopping cart? WHMCS

Tags: php, whm, whmcs

I installed whmcs in a subdomain in order to start selling domains and hosting. The problem is that adding a product to the cart does not redirect me to the cart or checkout page but instead executes the ajax action. Are there any settings on the dashboard to enable redirection? If it can't be done in the dashboar, is there a hook that does it?

Comment: In WHMCS you order domains and products, which are added tot the cart. If you follow steps will see Review and Check page with a link to checkout. Are you using default templates?

Comment: @wesamly Thank you so much for your answer. I think that is not what I really need. What I require is that when adding a product or domain to my shopping cart, I am immediately redirected to the shopping cart and not that I perform this action with ajax.
Answering your question, yes I am using a default template.

Comment: I don't know any configurations that change this behaviour, try other cart templates may be one of them do what you want.

Comment: @wesamly Thank you! excellent observation. I'll try another template and we'll see what happens, though I'd like more to get the code and add it to my current template.